# Regulator controller current capability

Tags: buck, switching-regulator, high-current

I am tasked with the design of a board that needs a buck regulator.

This regulator will work on low voltages (Vin ~= 12V, Vout ~= 4V), but high output current is required (> 60A).

I decided to use the [LM27402](https://www.ti.com/product/LM27402) ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm27402.pdf?ts=1646410956347&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM27402)), as most of its features are perfect for my application.

However, TI advertises this IC with a maximum output current capability of 30A.
This is a regulator *controller* (uses an external switch), so how can this component have a current limit?

As I see, no power flows through this IC. All power components are external.
Provided that I use a set of capable FETs and a beefy inductor, why can't I go up to 60A?

What limits the current that this IC can provide?

Comment: Although that limitation appears on the product summary page, it does NOT appear anywhere in the actual datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that simple.

> As I see, no power flows through this IC.

HG and LG drive the gates of the external MOSFETs. This is a very real load, and will cause the chip to draw significant current over time, likely several hundred milliamps at least.  This is also not listed in the datasheet parameters (because it depends on many variables.)

> This is a regulator controller (uses an external switch), so how can this component have a current limit?

Because the MOSFETs become challenging to switch quickly at these speeds.  The MOSFET gates have capacitance, and that must be charged and discharged quickly, which takes power and time.  The bigger the FET, the more capacitance it has usually.

> Provided that I use a set of capable FETs and a beefy inductor, why can't I go up to 60A?

You can *try*, but this chip was specifically designed to operate under certain parameters, and you are attempting to *double* some of those parameters.  The datasheet notes that:

```
7.3.10 Power MOSFET Gate Drivers
The LM27402 gate driver impedances are low enough to perform effectively
in high output current applications where large die-size or paralleled MOSFETs 
with correspondingly large gate charge, QG, are used.
```

Then,

```
The LM27402 is fully compatible with discrete NexFET™ Power Block MOSFETs from TI.
```

Seems they suggest a series of compatible components.  And,

```
8.1.11 MOSFET Gate Drivers
To drive large power MOSFETs with high gate charge, the LM27402 includes low 
impedance high-side and lowside gate drivers that source and sink high current 
for fast transition times and increased efficiency.
```

However the specs for these gate drivers only show their DC resistance at 100mA drive current.

For 2x beefier MOSFETs, the gate capacitance is going to be significantly more, so if the chip can *only* supply +/-100mA, those will switch roughly 2x slower, which is a deal-breaker.  And the Cboot capacitor will work 2x harder, "to boot."

You could try a different chip (no Cboot needed) and external gate drivers, like 1A rated, but then run the risk of timing issues due to gate driver delay.

This is why high-power supplies are more complex than regular supplies - all of these details add up to make controlling them more difficult.

Comment: In the datasheet, in one of the example designs, TI uses the SiR436DP. This has Qg = 13nC. I see that similar FETs exist, with much higher current rating, like CSD16403Q5A. So, it seems possible to use this IC for higher current. Or I am missing anything else?

Comment: You could certainly try those FETs, they look promising.  Just remember to consider all aspects of the design and keep things within operating parameters as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the reason for a suggested current range for a controller is the strength of the gate driver outputs.  As MOSFETs current ratings go up, the total gate charge and gate capacitance increase.  If the controller has trouble driving the FETs it will lead to much higher switching losses, or even cross conduction.

Having said that, the ratings are often a guideline, and with proper choice of FETs you can often exceed the suggested maximum without any issues.  Doubling the suggested current might be tricky, so it might be better to select a controller targeted for higher output currents.